# Subgroups of free products

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be a free product of 2 groups with $G \neq Z_2*Z_2$ . i would like to know if the following assertion is correct :

Every almost nilpotent subgroup of G is contained in a unique maximal almost nilpotent subgroup .

Comment: How could it be true? Take $G=C_2\ast C_3$, and consider the two subgroups $C_2$ and $C_3$.  The only subgroup that contains both of them is all of $G$, which is certainly not virtually nilpotent (being virtually free and all).

Answer (score 0):

Read 1.1 here http://tinyurl.com/d3ybkmg

As the modular group $\,C_2*C_3\,$ is not torsion free, we cannot be sure of the existence of max. virt. nilpotent subgroups, as remarked in the above paper, yet I still don't fully understand Steve's point as why would we care about what happens to a subgroup containing ***two*** subgroups?